# Ng-template with kendo datepicker with different attributes

Tags: angular, click, handler, ng-template

I have two templates but I need optimize it to one template, the only different of that templates is that  one kendo datepicker has more viewing atributes. Is there any way to get one template and for example for one button the kendo datepiker has some atributes and for another clicking button the datepiker has different atributes and everything is on one template? With two templates everything is working fine.

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item flex-fill border-0">  
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-sm" (click)="generateReportDaily(itemListRef, 'pdf')">PDF</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-sm" (click)="generateReportDaily(itemListRef, 'csv')">CSV</button>          
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-sm" (click)="generateReportDaily(itemListRef, 'xlsx')">XLSX</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-sm" (click)="generateReportDaily(itemListRef, 'txt')">TXT</button>   
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item flex-fill border-0">
       
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-sm" (click)="generateReportMonthly(itemListRef1, 'pdf')">PDF</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-sm" (click)="generateReportMonthly(itemListRef1, 'csv')">CSV</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-sm" (click)="generateReportMonthly(itemListRef1, 'xlsx')">XLSX</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-sm" (click)="generateReportMonthly(itemListRef1, 'txt')">TXT</button>
    </li>
</ul>

<ng-template #itemListRef kendoCalendarMonthCellTemplate let-context="cellContext">
    <form>
        
        <div>
            <kendo-datepicker
            [(ngModel)]="reportStartEnd"
            [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
            </kendo-datepicker>
        </div>
     
        <div>
            <kendo-datepicker
            [(ngModel)]="reportEndDate"
            [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"> 
            </kendo-datepicker> 
        </div>
    </form>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #itemListRef1 kendoCalendarMonthCellTemplate let-context="cellContext">
    <form>
        
        <div>
            <kendo-datepicker
            [(ngModel)]="reportStartDate"
            [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
            bottomView="year"
            topView="decade"
            format="MMMM yyyy"
            >
            </kendo-datepicker>
        </div>
       
        <div>
            <kendo-datepicker
            [(ngModel)]="reportEndDate"
            [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
            bottomView="year"
            topView="decade"
            format="MMMM yyyy">
            </kendo-datepicker>
        </div>
    </form>
</ng-template>
```

With two templates its working fine byt is there any way to make it on one?
Do you thing the click event handler will handle it?

https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2#add-the-click-event-handler